# Need help to replace share drive nested folders with SharePoint

Tags: permissions, folder, network-drive

We used to make use of shared network drive to share various reports to our staffs. The report administrator will create the nested folder structure and assign permission using [CACLS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx) command line tool. Then export various reports to these folders.

The nested folder is like:

```
Report>DeptA>RegionA>TeamA
Report>DeptA>RegionA>TeamB
Report>DeptA>RegionB>TeamC
Report>DeptB>RegionA>TeamX
```

All the subfolder have individual permission (broken inheritance). TeamA subfolder can only be read by Team A's members. There are more than 100 teams.

Every month the nested folder structure and the team formation will be changed based on new business need. Team members will be switched to different team. Some staffs will belong to multiple teams.

Although the change is complex, in current setup, the report administrator just need to spend 15 minutes to update his DOS script file and make change using [CACLS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx).

The problem is, we have to replace this share drive setup with SharePoint 2013 Enterprise on-premise. We create a site collection and assign the report administrator as site collection admin. He cannot have PowerShell access. By using SharePoint UI, he can break inheritance of folders and create SharePoint groups for 100+ teams, and then assign permission folder by folder. However it will take him entire day and easily make mistake. Then repeat this painful process every month.

Do you have suggestion to ease his job? I am not looking for identical setup as before. Any method that don't need him repeat same steps 100 times for 100 folders is fine. Also I want to avoid farm solution because I heard it is going to be phased out.

Thank you for any idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're talking reports from SSRS, then an option would be to create a document library for each team and secure it as desired. In the configuration of each library, email enable the document libraries with unique email addresses.

Then on the SSRS end, configure the reports to be emailed to this email address. The reports will end up in the respective libraries and no one will have to do anything ever again, except for group permissions management which could be delegated to someone else.

I did this back in the 2007 days when I was generating a lot of SSRS reports from our help desk software and they would automatically show up once executed on schedule, was amazingly easy.

Comment: It is not SSRS report. It is a VB program generate CSV like reports from an Access database.

Comment: and the painful process is still there using Doc Lib approach. The report admin have to break inheritance for each Doc Lib (100+) and assign permission.

Comment: that could be done easily enough with powershell to create the libraries and break permission inheritance, something to consider

Comment: He is not Sharepoint admin so he cannot use PowerShell. It is easy for me set them up but I want to avoid it become our regular task.